# Is there r functions to sort these data out in R?

Tags: r

Here is a small sample of my data:

```
dat<-read.table (text=" ID  A   S   T   R1  R2  R3
1   10  21  80  60  80  44
2   15  14  90  70  76  40
3   22  10  20  90  55  33
", header=TRUE)
```

Column A searches in column S to find the nearest number. ID1 Corespondes to R1, ID2 coresponds to R2 and ID3 corespondes to R3. When the number is funded in S, the corresponding R-value to ID is selected.
For example, in ID2, the nearest value in the S is 14 for 15, so 76 in R2 is selected. The outcome table is as follow:

```
ID  A   S   T   out
1   10  21  80  44
2   15  14  90  76
3   22  10  20  90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```r
rows    <- apply(outer(dat$A, dat$S, function(a, b) abs(a - b)), 1, which.min)
cols    <-  grep("R\\d+", names(dat))
indices <- cbind(rows, cols)
cbind(dat[1:4], out = dat[indices])
```

Comment: I run  it on actual data, i.e,  R1 to R 100, I do not get the desired outcome

Comment: @user330 can you try the updated version?

Comment: I get the same results, Sorry

Comment: @user330 can you give a larger sample of your data? Both tmfmnk and I use essentially the same logic and get the desired result from the sample data frame, following the steps you describe. Can you show where in your own data the answer is not correct?

Comment: If you try this, you will see does not follow your codes. dat<-read.table (text=" ID A S T R1 R2 R3 out
1 60 59 12 999 0.11 0.67 999
2 99 79 11 44 999 34 200
3 80 98 8 0.55 200 33 34
", header=TRUE)

Comment: @user330 I think I understand now. See my latest update, which works on your new example too, and is designed to be a little clearer so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to a solution already presented but without `rowwise`

```r
dat %>%
  mutate(idx = map_int(A, ~ which.min(abs(.x - S)))) %>%
  mutate(., out = select(., R1:R3)[cbind(row_number(), idx)]) |>
  select(-idx, -c(R1:R3))

##>   ID  A  S  T out
##> 1  1 10 21 80  44
##> 2  2 15 14 90  76
##> 3  3 22 10 20  90
```